# Exercise about Riemann integrable in Analysis.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that f is Riemann integrable on [0,1] and $-10<f<10$ on [0,1].

Let Q:={0=$y_0$ < $y_1$ < .... < $y_{10}$ =1 } and U(f:Q) - L(f:Q) < 1/2.

Let P={0=$x_0$, $x_1$, ... $x_n$=1} with llPll < 1/800.

Show that U(f:P)-L(f:P)<1.

First I describe real line and marked $y_n$'s.
Next I deployed the upper and lower sums about Q.

I tried here but I don't know how to do next.

Can you help me? :)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: thanks :) I edited.

Comment: That was not really much of an improvement.